# Why Sub Category Links aren't working

Tags: category, category-products

Created some new subcategories but when I set up the links, I get a 404 error even if its working on backend. e.g. this link doesn't work

https://www.jadeed.store/categories/personal-care/electric-massager.html

But the version I had to implement based on a filter? That worked but it was a makeshift solution

https://www.jadeed.store/categories/personal-care.html?cat=267_electric-massager

Problem is that its not a one time thing and several categories and their subcategories are having the same issue. Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check after reindexing.

```
php bin/magento indexer: reindex
```

Or check the category URL in `URL Rewrite` list in admin.

Comment: System automatically reindexes and problem still persists. Regarding URL Rewrite, settings are normal. Adjusted as usual.

Comment: Also, this problem persists only with the new subcategories I make. Older ones function fine

Comment: Please use this extension for URL  :        https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites